# Chromium never stops loading iGoogle

Tags: browser, website, chromium

I almost always keep a tab open on google.com/ig. Recently I've noticed that the "loading" animation for that tab never stops spinning, even though the page appears to be fully loaded. Even though there's no direct problem with this, I find the animation really distracting and to be honest it's driving me crazy.

I've done a few things to try to figure this out. I've removed every single one of my gadgets (so my igoogle is blank), but that made no difference. I've disabled adblock and scriptno. nothing. I've watched the network console in developer tools to look for resources that haven't finished loading, but it looks like everything is done. I'm all out of ideas.

For my sanity's sake, please help.